# Wordpress: Need to do large MySQL update job multiprocessing

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, pthreads, pcntl

Hi so I have an issue with an operation that takes place once a week where thousands of rows in the database need to be updated with new information. At the moment this happens relatively slowly where each item takes 1 second to update where I need to happen much quicker. I have looked into multiprocessing the whole operation but have found that you can't and shouldn't do this in a web server setting.

Here is some example code of what is happening now:

```
$data_array = function_to_get_data_from_database();

foreach (data_array as $data) {
      $new_data = new_data_status($data['id']);
      if ($new_data['status'] == 'YES') {
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           $data = get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array($data));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
      }
      else {
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
      }
}
```

I would like it do this:

```
    $data_array = function_to_get_data_from_database();
    $first_data_array = get_first_half_of_array($data_array);
    $second_data_array = get_second_half_of_array($data_array);

    foreach (first_data_array as $data) {
         $new_data = new_data_status($data['id']);
         if ($new_data['status'] == 'YES') {
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           $data = get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array($data));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
         }
         else {
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
         }
    }
    // Do this concurrently
    foreach (second_data_array as $data) {
         $new_data = new_data_status($data['id']);
         if ($new_data['status'] == 'YES') {
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           $data = get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array($data));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
           get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
           update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
         }
         else {
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
            get_user_meta($user_id , 'data');
            update_user_meta($user_id, array(new info));
         }
    }
```

How can I go about achieving this?

I have thought of anther possible solution which may work but would like to get advice to if it's a good solution.

I would do the same as above but create two functions which do the same but one would loop through the array from top to bottom and the other from bottom to top and I would do a check on each item do see if it's already been done and save in a column to note if it's been processed already. I would then activate them through a couple of buttons.

I have implemented this but would still like advice for better ways. I would like it to be faster still, which i could do by splitting up the items more into quarters to have four processes working on them.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much of that one second is spent calculating what to save, and how much is spent actually performing the `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Time spend calculating what to save is much less than the update part of the function. Ideally, it would be sending jobs to the database concurrently to the other process.

Comment: If you're spending nearly a second to update a single row then you've likely got an unindexed `WHERE` clause on your query.

Comment: My code is very simplistic compared to what actually happens. There are about 8 selects to the database and around 6 updates to the database for each item.

Comment: 6 updates per second is still absurdly slow. I'm getting about 350 on my ancient development server. Run an `EXPLAIN` on your update queries.

Comment: The updates are mostly using the wordpress update_user_meta() function which are indexed. The usermeta table has over 100,000 rows however. Could that be why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163511/discussion-between-alex-haines-and-alex-howansky).